# SQL Server 2005: column cannot be persisted because is non-deterministic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a calculated field (`Test`) based on the result of a function (`MyFunctionTest`) and i want make it `PERSISTED` and add an index for performance improvments, eg.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Foo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Test]  AS ([dbo].[MyFunctionTest]([Foo])) PERSISTED,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

`MyFunctionTest` is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunctionTest]
(
    @foo int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @foo * 2
END
```

But, sql server 2005 on save show the error

> Computed column 'Test' in table 'Tmp_TestTable' cannot be
>   persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

why `MyFunctionTest` isn't deterministic?

**SOLUTION**

Add **WITH SCHEMABINDING** to the function make it deterministic

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunctionTest]
(
    @foo int
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @foo * 2
END
```

Comment: Why do you need a function to do a simple task such as the multiplying by 2? What wrong with `Test AS Foo * 2 PERSISTED`?

Comment: Btw: SQL-Server 2005 is a walking dead, deprecated for centuries... You really should consider an upgrade...

Comment: @Larnu is just an example